# Cannot install lighttpd on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, lighttpd

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I can't find out what's causing this error. I tried to google but couldn't find the solution. Please help.

```
sudo apt install lighttpd -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  spawn-fcgi
Suggested packages:
  rrdtool php5-cgi lighttpd-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lighttpd spawn-fcgi
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 291 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,027 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 lighttpd amd64 1.4.45-1ubuntu3 [276 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 spawn-fcgi amd64 1.6.4-2 [14.9 kB]                        
Fetched 291 kB in 8s (35.0 kB/s)                                                                                       
Selecting previously unselected package lighttpd.
(Reading database ... 358529 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lighttpd_1.4.45-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lighttpd (1.4.45-1ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package spawn-fcgi.
Preparing to unpack .../spawn-fcgi_1.6.4-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking spawn-fcgi (1.6.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-5) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Setting up spawn-fcgi (1.6.4-2) ...
Setting up lighttpd (1.4.45-1ubuntu3) ...
Job for lighttpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status lighttpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript lighttpd, action "start" failed.
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-06-17 13:28:45 IST; 9ms ago
  Process: 25574 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=127)
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
```

lighttpd is not starting

```
systemctl status lighttpd.service 
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-06-17 13:28:47 IST; 1min 53s ago
  Process: 25986 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=127)

Jun 17 13:28:47 surjit systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 17 13:28:47 surjit systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 7.
Jun 17 13:28:47 surjit systemd[1]: Stopped Lighttpd Daemon.
Jun 17 13:28:47 surjit systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 17 13:28:47 surjit systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 17 13:28:47 surjit systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
```

Comment: Check for errors with `journalctl -u lighttpdlighttpd` and in */var/log/lighttpd/error.log* .

Comment: On clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I can't reproduce the error. You should check that `lighttpd` is only one HTTP server (have exclusive access to port HTTP/80 ). Please add output of `sudo netstat -p -l | grep http` to the question.

Comment: I have Apache web server installed.. that's why I stopped the server before installing lighttpd. And also there's no log file.. may lighttpd is not configured properly.

Comment: See my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072840/failed-to-start-lighttpd-daemon-on-boot/1113413#1113413