# Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon on boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, lighttpd

Every time I turn on my laptop, I see this error message about [Lighttpd](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lighttpd) appearing several times while booting process (also on `systemctl --failed`):

```
Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
See 'systemctl status lighttpd.service' for details.
```

After logging in, I typed `systemctl status lighttpd.service` and got this output:

```
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-09-06 20:54:16 +05; 22min ago
  Process: 1170 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=127)

Sen 06 20:54:16 ibrokhim-i systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sen 06 20:54:16 ibrokhim-i systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sen 06 20:54:16 ibrokhim-i systemd[1]: Stopped Lighttpd Daemon.
Sen 06 20:54:16 ibrokhim-i systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sen 06 20:54:16 ibrokhim-i systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sen 06 20:54:16 ibrokhim-i systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
```

Also, this is the output from `cat /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Edit your question and show me **more /var/log/lighttpd/error.log**. Report back to @heynnema. Do you use this webserver? Is apache2 installed also?

Comment: @heynnema I thought bionic used `gdm3`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen bionic **does** use gdm3... or lightdm. This OP is asking about **lighttpd**, which is a web server.

Comment: What webserver is this @heynnema?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen look in Synaptic.

Comment: @heynnema There's no error.log in /var/log/lighttpd/ - the folder is empty. And also, I don't know what the webserver is in the first place. I think apache2 is not installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug that's been around for years, if [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lighttpd/+bug/1453463) is anything to go by. Several users in the comments of that bug claim that installing the [`gamin`](https://people.gnome.org/%7Eveillard/gamin/) [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gamin) solves this issue.

I haven't done any extensive testing, but it seems to be a solution. Running `sudo apt install --reinstall lighttpd` normally shows that it fails to start `lighttpd`. However, after installing `gamin`, the output looks like it normally would for any successful package installation. `systemctl status` also shows `lighttpd` as active and running now.

Note that the package [`libfam0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libfam0) gets removed when installing `gamin`. I don't know what it's for, or what packages may depend on it, so keep that in mind, unless someone else can comment as to its usefulness and necessity.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Worked on Lubuntu 20.04 (Fecal Fossa).

Answer (score 4):

I solved with this:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/lighttpd/
```

Comment: Worked for me. Might also be helpful to `chmod 755 /var/log/lighttpd` in conjunction with the above command

Answer (score 0):

So I had to do a purge to rid the system of the extra files:

```
sudo apt-get purge lighttpd
```

Then reinstall the software

```
sudo apt-get install lighttpd
```

This reset all of the .conf files, and other files